# Extracting variables from jinja templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm working on a program to extract variables from jinja templates.

So far this works fine:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.nodes import Assign

template = "{% set x = 1%}"
env = Environment()
ast = env.parse(template)

assert {n.target.name: n.node.as_const() for n in ast.find_all(Assign)} == {'x': 1}
```

But users might use custom classes that have certain formatting logic, so I attemped  passing `Custom` to `env.globals` like this:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.nodes import Assign

class Custom:
    def __init__(self, value):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

template = "{% set x = Custom(1) %}"
env = Environment()
env.globals['Custom'] = Custom
ast = env.parse(template)

{n.target.name: n.node.as_const() for n in ast.find_all(Assign)} 
# I'd like this to be: {'x': Custom(1)}
```

But I get this error:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/ploomber/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py in as_const(self, eval_ctx)
    416            the `eval_ctx` parameter was added.
    417         """
--> 418         raise Impossible()
    419
    420     def can_assign(self):

Impossible:
```

I also tried passing `Custom` to `eval_ctx` in the `as_const()` function, but I get the same error.

What is the appropriate way to make `Environment` aware of `Custom`?

Thanks!

- Python version: 3.6.10
- Jinja version: 2.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the source code and this is not possible as of version 2.11.2.

When building the code's AST, `Custom(1)` is parsed as a `jinja2.nodes.Call` node, which is a subclass of `jinja2.nodes.Expr`.

The `Expr.as_const` method is not implemented, it just raises an exception (`raise Impossible()`).